# Hide search result if focus is not on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying to hide search results if the focus is not on the search input. I am able to do that easily by using `.blur()` after the `.keyup()` function. My issue is that when a user clicks on the search result... it still hides. So, I want to make it so if the user removes focus from the text input AND user does not focus on search result then only hide the `div`

HTML:

```
<form role="search" autocomplete="off">
  <div>
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <div class="search_main">
    <div id="sresult" tabindex="0"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function(e) {
  var q = $(this).val();
  if (q !== undefined && q.length > 0) {
  $("#sresult").show(150);
    $("#sresult").html("No results");
  } else {
    $("#sresult").hide(150);
  }
}).blur(function(e) {
  $("#sresult").hide(150);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ten3ur4e/1/)**

Comment: Due to there is no such condition you have given to remain visible your search result.

Comment: You have to remove the blur chaining function if you want to remain visible and define other thing when it should hide.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple add multiple events using `on` event handlers

```
element.on('event1 event2 etc...')
```

Your event would be like this

```
$("#searchInput").on('keyup click',function(e) {
    var q = $(this).val();
    if (q !== undefined && q.length > 0) {
        $("#sresult").show(150);
        $("#sresult").html("No results");
    } else {
        $("#sresult").hide(150);
    }
}).blur(function(e) {
    $("#sresult").hide(150);
});
```

This way by the time element is click or keyup the function will be executed which shown your result

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ten3ur4e/10/)

Hope this help you

Comment: It's still closing when I click "No results"

Comment: It is because of your blur event

Comment: I know... which is why my question was to hide "No results" only if the user doesn't click on "No results" or focus on the textbox